# Conditions for $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ to converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Given a sequence $a_n \to 0$. I'm looking for a necessary and sufficient condition for $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ to converge.

Comment: $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges is a necessary and sufficient condition.

Answer (score -3):

In general, the form $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ will converge if the limit of this is $<1$. If the above holds, then write $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for every index $n$. This is the definition of a monotonically decreasing function. 
A necessary condition would be that $a_n \neq 0.$ Monotonically decreasing would be a sufficient condition. Also, non-negativity of the sequence follows from $a_n\neq 0$ since $a_n=0\Rightarrow  a_{n+1}<0.$